How to obtain more testnet Eth
How do you get a lot of Sepolia testnet eth?? I know of a couple faucets but they only give like .01 per week and that barely pays for a transaction fee for any kind of testing. Thanks!

You can refer to this post.

It's better to use a  cheap mainnet like Arbitrum for testing. Transactions cost ~$0.01 and you do not have any stability issues or missing contracts like you have with testnets.

I mostly use https://sepolia-faucet.pk910.de/ and multiple faucets, but yeah it's time taking

It is best to do most of your testing with a local blockchain so you can easily generate new funds. If you need more Sepolia ETH you can mine the various faucets and/or use the proof of work faucet here: https://sepolia-faucet.pk910.de/.  You can also purchase Sepolia ETH if you are desperate here: https://www.sepoliaeth.com/.
